# Problems with loading and saving strings from an array

Tags: android, arrays, string, load, save

So I've done research on this topic and there are many ways of doing a favorite for a string in an array. There is a favorite button that the user clicks on to favorite that particular displayed string which would be in an array. I've come up with a load array and save array method in this class. I'm getting my errors at loadArray(favorites, this); and saveArray(favorites, "favorites", this); It does not seem to recognize loadArray or saveArray as a method. Thanks so much!

```
public class Base extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button home, search, moreapps, fav;
    TextView display;
    String [] favorites;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(starting.rt.R.layout.relationship);
        home = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Home);
        search = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.search);
        moreapps = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.moreapps);
        fav = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.fav);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.tvResults);
        fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                display.getText();
                loadArray(favorites, this);
                favorites = Arrays.copyOf(favorites, favorites.length+1);
                favorites[favorites.length]=display.getText().toString();
                saveArray(favorites, "favorites", this);

            }
        }); 
    }

    public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
        int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
        String array[] = new String[size];  
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
            array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
        return array;  
    }  

    public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
        editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
            editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
        return editor.commit();  
    } 
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because **this** in that scope is the *onClickListener()*, you could use **Base.this** to reference the *Activity* (Context).

I wouldn't recommend using *[getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)*, the documentation saids:

> This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose
>   lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the
>   lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

Comment: Worked for SaveArray not load array

Comment: You could also remove the _Context_ argument from __loadArray()__ and __saveArray()__ and call `getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);` because they are part of the _Activity_ class which is already a context.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
 loadArray(String[], View.OnClickListener)
```

instead of

```
 loadarray(String, Context)
```

"favorites" is a array of strings, not a string

"this" refers to View.OnclickListener instead of Context

You can get the Context using "getApplicationContext()"